# How to implement multiple left joins in Django ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models

I have 3 models:

```
class Companies(models.Model):
cin = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
br_section = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
adress_line = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
last_update = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'companies'


class OrPodanieIssues(models.Model):
bulletin_issue = models.ForeignKey(BulletinIssues, models.DO_NOTHING)
raw_issue = models.ForeignKey('RawIssues', models.DO_NOTHING)
br_mark = models.CharField(max_length=256)
br_court_code = models.CharField(max_length=256)
br_court_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
kind_code = models.CharField(max_length=256)
kind_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
cin = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
registration_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
corporate_body_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
br_section = models.CharField(max_length=256)
br_insertion = models.CharField(max_length=256)
text = models.TextField()
created_at = models.DateTimeField()
updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
address_line = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
street = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
company = models.ForeignKey(Companies, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)


class ZnizenieImaniaIssues(models.Model):
bulletin_issue = models.ForeignKey(BulletinIssues, models.DO_NOTHING)
raw_issue = models.OneToOneField(RawIssues, models.DO_NOTHING)
corporate_body_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
street = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
building_number = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
br_court_code = models.CharField(max_length=256)
br_court_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
br_section = models.CharField(max_length=256)
br_insertion = models.CharField(max_length=256)
cin = models.BigIntegerField()
decision_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
decision_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
equity_currency_code = models.CharField(max_length=256)
old_equity_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
new_equity_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
resolution_store_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
first_ov_released_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
first_ov_released_number = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField()
updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
company = models.ForeignKey(Companies, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'znizenie_imania_issues'
    unique_together = (('updated_at', 'id'),)
```

I want to join companies with the 2 other table when fk company = companies.cin and count the occurences of the cin value in two other tables. So the output should look like this:

```
cin 9110007690010
name:   "Alžbeta Škrováňová"
br_section: null
adress_line:    "Za Humnami, 95161 Čifáre"
last_update:    "2018-09-19T03:00:32.851"
or_podanie_issues_count:    3
znizenie_imania_issues_count    null
```

As you can see in ths example or_podanie_issues count means that cin 9110007690010 is in or_podanie issue table 3 times. In znizenie_imania_issues is 0 times so i want to return null as number of occuerences.

I have this raw PostrgeSQL query, which gives me the correct result (the one showed above):

```
SELECT ov.companies.cin, ov.companies.name, ov.companies.br_section, ov.companies.adress_line,
ov.companies.last_update, podanie.or_podanie_issues_count, znizenie.znizenie_imania_issues_count FROM ov.companies LEFT JOIN(
SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) AS or_podanie_issues_count FROM ov.or_podanie_issues
GROUP BY company_id) podanie ON podanie.company_id = ov.companies.cin 
LEFT JOIN( SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) AS znizenie_imania_issues_count
FROM ov.znizenie_imania_issues GROUP BY company_id) znizenie ON znizenie.company_id = ov.companies.cin
```

But I dont know how to write this query in Django ORM.

Thank you for your answers!